# what does this sort command mean? cat temp.txt | sort -t$'\t'

Tags: linux, bash

In the man page of sort, -t is used to specify a field-separator. However, I don't know what the `-t$'\t'` form means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bash ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html). If you wrap a string like this `$'string'`, it is expanded with the same rules as C string. In your case `$'t'` becomes just `'t'`, but if it was `$'\t'` it would become a tab character. This is a bit different than using the double quotes, as in `"string"` because double quotes allow for bash substitution (for example, variable expansion)

Comment: Is there any difference between `$''` and just `''`?  Single quotes don't allow for bash substitution.

Comment: @user3872279 but single quotes don't allow for escape sequences as well: if you write `'\t'` you get a backslash and a t, if you write `$'\t'` you get a tab character

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The '$' after the -t option is used to specify a character that uses more than 7 bits for it's representation. For example for a newline : '\n', for a tab '\t'. If you do it like this :

```
sort -t '\t'
```

Sort will probably prints you an  error saying that you're using too many characters because it tries to literally reads the '\' and the 't'.

Thus in your example, the backslash is ommited.

It's the same for example with the cut command :

```
cut -d$'\t'
```

Comment: Tab character can be represented with 7 bits (it is actually ASCII 9), and using a dollar sign before a a `'` quoted string will result in escape codes being interpreted correctly inside it (that is, `$'\t'` is actually the same as `"\t"`)